# creating user and password in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges

```
CREATE USER STUDENT IDENTIFIED BY "pass12";
```

I am creating user and password by this syntax but getting error:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

User you're currently connected to doesn't have privileges to create other users.

One of such is my `SCOTT` user:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create user student identified by pass12;
create user student identified by pass12
                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

But, if I connect as a privileged user (such as `SYS`), then:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create user student identified by pass12;

User created.

SQL>
```